# Nginx proxy_pass and absolute paths

Tags: node.js, nginx, path, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to run some nodejs app on a server (Ubuntu 14.04), using Nginx and i'm almost done. Here's my server configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_domain.com;

    location /test1 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /test2 {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I've got several apps running, and they all works well, i can acces them with `http://my_domain.com/test1`, `http://my_domain.com/test2`, etc...

The problem is that inside one of this apps i've got several absolute paths:
e.g. `<a href="/">Home</a>`
or (inside express)
`res.redirect('/');`

This redirects don't go to `http://my_domain.com/test1` but they go to `http://my_domain.com/`
Is there a way, through nginx configurations, to tell the app that the root location is actually `http://my_domain.com/test1`?

I'm really new to nginx and to virtual hosts in general, i'm trying to learn... Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The result of `curl -I http://127.0.0.1:5000` is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1376
ETag: W/"560-GGm/YYltkhKxiOVNZ99jqQ"
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AkZYCqLKvbhHhK3W8ECBN8G91s41paws4.ekLWefrd3NdQatT3VzFNozfnFs65YBEW9k9MNTdbQT0; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Sat, 15 Aug 2015 13:13:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

As you can see i don't get a `Location` Header...
By the way, i managed to solve the problem using subdomains, that seem to work as i expected... Anyway an answer would be appreciated, since i might need it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use curl to check the header `Location` value which is used by client to redirect. e.g. `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5001/myappp`
2. Use [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) to change the `Location` header